# How to use Appsetting configuration for Akka.Net 1.3.0 Configuration in Asp.net core

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, akka.net, .net-standard

I have been playing around with the new version of Akka.Net that support .NetStandard 1.6 in visual studio 2017. Due to the peculiarity of Akka.Net Configuration which uses HOCON format for its configuration. The previous version embeds easy-to-read HOCON configuraton inside app.config or Web.config. Another option is to use ConfigurationFactory.ParseString method which accepts string object. But parsing HOCON from a string is handy for small configuration sections. In my case, i was left with  this ParseString configuration which didn't even work as expected.
I came up with this:

```
 var configString = @"akka {
        log-config-on-start = on
        stdout-loglevel = INFO
        loglevel = DEBUG
        loggers= ""[Akka.Logger.Serilog.SerilogLogger, Akka.Logger.Serilog]""
        actor {

                    debug {
                        receive = on
                        autoreceive = on
                        lifecycle = on
                        event-stream = on
                        unhandled = on
                    }
              }

    akka.persistence {
        journal {
                    plugin = ""akka.persistence.journal.sqlite""

                    sqlite {
                                    class = ""Akka.Persistence.Sqlite.Journal.SqliteJournal, Akka.Persistence.Sqlite""
                                        plugin-dispatcher = ""akka.actor.default-dispatcher""
                                        connection-string = ""Data Source = F:\\SqliteDb\\Sample.db3""
                                      table-name = event_journal
                                    metadata-table-name = journal_metadata
                                    auto-initialize = on

                            }
                    }

    snapshot-store {
        plugin = ""akka.persistence.snapshot-store.sqlite""
        sqlite {
            class = ""[Akka.Persistence.Sqlite.Snapshot.SqliteSnapshotStore, Akka.Persistence.Sqlite]""
            connection-string = ""Data Source = F:\\SqliteDb\\Sample.db3""
            table-name = snapshot_store
            auto-initialize = on

        }
}

}

     ";
        var config = ConfigurationFactory.ParseString(configString);
         ActorSystem.Create("AkkaSystem", config);
```

which didn't work as expected.
How do we configure akka.net in Asp.Net core using appsetting.json? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: My workaround for now   . I created A file. Make it an embedded resource. then load it through ConfigurationFactory.FromResource<Startup>("resoucefilename.txtt");

Comment: At the moment there's no canonical way for doing this - we're discussing adding one in a minor release coming up.

Comment: check my answer to a similair question here  :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36699889/akka-net-asp-net-5-mvc-6-configuration-for-hocon/46568515#46568515

Answer (score 5):

I converted the hocon to json and use ConfigurationFactory.FromObject and some classes that have the properties that I'm interested in, to read the akka-config from appsettings. The anonymous object simulates the hocon root.

```cs
var config = ConfigurationFactory.FromObject(new { akka = configuration.GetSection("Akka").Get<AkkaConfig>() });

actorSystem = ActorSystem.Create("Stimpy", config);
```

Notice that I haven't bothered to figure out how to parse kebab-case properties from appsettings. So I have just renamed the properties excluding the hyphens. Then set the JsonProperty-attribute to the correct name so that FromObject can deserialize it correctly.

```cs
public class AkkaConfig
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "log-config-on-start")]
    public string logconfigonstart { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "stdout-loglevel")]
    public string stdoutloglevel { get; set; }
    public string loglevel { get; set; }
    public string[] loggers { get; set; }
    public ActorConfig actor { get; set; }

    public class ActorConfig
    {
        public DebugConfig debug { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> serializers { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "serialization-bindings")]
        public Dictionary<string, string> serializationbindings { get; set; }

        public class DebugConfig
        {
            public string receive { get; set; }
            public string autoreceive { get; set; }
            public string lifecycle { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "event-stream")]
            public string eventstream { get; set; }
            public string unhandled { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace"
    }
  },
  "Akka": {
    "logconfigonstart":"on",
    "stdoutloglevel":"INFO",
    "loglevel": "DEBUG",
    "loggers": [ "Akka.Logger.NLog.NLogLogger, Akka.Logger.NLog" ],

    "actor": {
      "debug": {
        "receive": "on",
        "autoreceive": "on",
        "lifecycle": "on",
        "eventstream": "on",
        "unhandled": "on"
      },
      "serializers": {
        "hyperion": "Akka.Serialization.HyperionSerializer, Akka.Serialization.Hyperion"
      },
      "serializationbindings": {
        "System.Object": "hyperion"
      }
    }
  }
}
```