# How can I fix the "Input string was not in a correct format" in Akka.Event.LogMessage

Tags: logging, .net-core, serilog, akka.net

I am using Akka.Net with Akka.Logger.Serilog. In my appsettings I use 
`loggers = ["Akka.Logger.Serilog.SerilogLogger, Akka.Logger.Serilog"]`

In `Program.cs`, I use:

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
    .UseSerilog((ctx, config) =>
             config.ReadFrom.Configuration(ctx.Configuration), true);
```

In `Startup.cs`, I have tried with or without

```
services.AddSingleton<ILoggingAdapter, SerilogLoggingAdapter>();
```

and in my actors, I use the following to get the initialize the logger:

```
ILoggingAdapter _logger = Context.GetLogger(); // and Logger.GetLogger(Context);
// then
_logger.Info("Message loaded: {@Message}", message);
// and this _logger.Info("Message loaded: {Message}", message);
```

And various other combinations of the above, but each time,

In the console I see some of my own logs, but I see the following message everywhere:

```
[ERROR][12/30/2019 12:43:47][Thread 0010][akka://MyActorSystem/system/log1-DefaultLogger] Input string was not in a correct format. Cause: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.FormatError()
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at System.String.Format(String format, Object[] args)
   at Akka.Event.DefaultLogMessageFormatter.Format(String format, Object[] args)
```

Is there another step to ensure that Akka.net uses the right logging adapter?

How do I control what the default logger uses?

Answer (score 1):

In the end, it was 2 things:

1. The challenges of loading HOCON from JSON, which was solved by:
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/47997504/474702 remember that the casing
   matters, so I used `[JsonProperty("property-name")]` liberally.
2. You need to load Serilog properly in the `Program.cs`

See below:

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
    .UseSerilog((ctx, config) => 
        config
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(ctx.Configuration)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext())
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    });
```

Once I got it working, I was able to see the changes in the logs:

```
[DEBUG][12/30/2019 17:02:38][Thread 0005][akka://MyActorSystem/system/log1-SerilogLogger] Started (Akka.Logger.Serilog.SerilogLogger)
[INFO][12/30/2019 17:02:38][Thread 0005][[akka://MyActorSystem/system/log1-SerilogLogger#121623868]] SerilogLogger started
```